# Как правильно: глассаж  или гляссаж?

Tags: заимствования, орфография

Термин из кондитерской отрасли, означает вид шоколадной глазури с добавлением желатина (используется для покрытия тортов и пирожных). В интернете встречаются оба варианта написания, но хотелось бы знать правильное/предпочтительное. Спасибо!

Comment: @Ольга Н, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Глассаж -от фр. glaçage — наведение глазури, эмали; глянцевание. Это и глазурь кондитерская, и глазурь на обуви (процесс полировки). Например, Мируар Глассаж Ноир  (Miroir Glassag Noir) - глазурь шоколадная.

Ему родственно "глоссарий" - возможно, как производное от Cloth (англ.),

Выходит, независимо от верной этимологии, более близкое по произношению  А, но произносят и мягко, приближая к слову "глянец". Так что как Вам нравится, пока это слово не вошло в словари, когда закрепят, тогда будем писать как положено, а пока - сами выбирайте.

Answer (score 1):

В кондитерском производстве слово "гляссе" используется с давних времён, это и масляный крем "гляссе", и кофе "глясе". Даже если названия произошли от разных французских слов, всё равно к такому произношению все привыкли и отвыкать вроде бы и нет особых причин. Безе, гляссе, меланж, льезон... Всех этих слов на русском нет, как говорится. Поэтому естественно, что при их произношении допускается некоторое "офранцуживание".